# Unexplicable increase in page load time

Tags: performance, load, vps, php-7

I'll try to be as brief as possible;

My page load time increased 40% and I don't know why, in the atttached image you have the before and after loading times, plus the waterfall view for both the first and the repeated view.

The setup: LNMP VPS, opcache, memcache, joomla with T3 framework template, using joomla file caching

I did the following changes (unfortunately I didn't think about testing after each individual change):
-upgraded to the latest joomla, template, and template engine
-compressed images
-upgraded to PHP 7 (from 5.6)
-everything else is the same, including using the same server for testing and having the same server load

The only explanation I can come up with is that the provider is overloading their servers, making my VPS slower.

Please feel free to write any insight/ideas you have.

Thanks!

[Screenshots from webpagetest.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQUTz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive testing on various other platforms, using the same setup (I even copy-pasted the config files for php, php-fpm, mysql, etc) I found out that the issue was the hosting company which seems to be overselling.

Using different but identically specced hosting the page now has a first view load time of ~0,9s.